# How to call Client ID in javascript without hardcoding it

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to include a jquery Pagination plugin in my website. I am having issues with using the correct selectors.

I use a CMS(DotNetNuke) for my website and my module.
I am creating the following control in my C# code

```
HtmlGenericControl Content = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
Content.ID = "content";
```

This gets generated as the following.

```
<div id="dnn_ctr441_StatusUpdate_content"></div>
```

Now in my client side code i have the following javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#content').jPaginate();
        });
```

I can change this to

```
 $('#dnn_ctr441_StatusUpdate_content').jPaginate();
```

and this would work. However i dont want to hard code this into the javascript.

what is the correct syntax to use in this case so i can call the correct ClientID without hardcoding it in the JS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
$('#<%= Content.ClientID %>').jPaginate();
```

Alternatively, you could use a class to identify the control (*assuming this is the only one on the page*):

```
HtmlGenericControl Content = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
Content.Attributes.Add("class", "foo");
```

And then:

```
$('.foo').jPaginate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ClientID` property of the control. Try this:

```
$('#<%= Content.ClientID %>').jPaginate();
```

Comment: There was hardly a difference of 8 millisec's between both your answers. But i think il mark Dgibbs as the answer for the alternative solution.

Comment: It was 8 seconds, but no problem, he added more detail to his answer.